# Using "find" on mac doesn't locate .so files

Tags: macos, shell, find

For some reason "find" doesn't locate .so files unless they're in the same directory I'm in. For example:

```
r-mbp:~ todd.r$ cd /usr/local/apache/modules/
r-mbp:modules todd.r$ ls
httpd.exp   libphp5.so
r-mbp:modules todd.r$ find . -name lib*
./libphp5.so
r-mbp:modules todd.r$ cd ..
r-mbp:apache todd.r$ find . -name lib*
./include/php/ext/date/lib
./lib
r-mbp:apache todd.r$
```

Any ideas? I'm looking for another instance of libphp5.so, but without being able to search from "/", I'm a bit stuck.

Comment: With many shells, you need to escape the asterisk, e.g. `find . -name lib\*`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know OSX, but with many shells, you need to escape the asterisk, e.g. `find . -name lib\*`.

Comment: This is the case. The asterisk is being expanded before it is passed to find as an argument.

Comment: This answer is correct. I'll add you'd probably get better results if you'd run something like `find -x / -type f -name libphp5.so`. Across your whole computer, many files and directories are likely to be called `lib*`.

Comment: yes - bash(1) also lists the order, because there is more than one expansion :-) "The order of expansions is: brace expansion, tilde expansion, parameter, variable and  arithmetic  expansion and command substitution (done in a left-to-right fashion), word splitting, and pathname expansion."

Comment: When I need to search with a `*`, I enclose it in `""` and it works.  `find . -name "lib*"`

Answer (score 2):

Give a try with double quote and/or sudo-ing :

```
> sudo find / -name "*.so"
```

will return all the .so of my system.